# Need help, https://mywebsite.com is redirecting to outside/ 3rd party website

Tags: php, http, url, redirect, https

I got an issue.

I am not using SSL in my website.

To explain lets assume that http://mywebsite.com is my website which i am hosting in my account.

1. when i type with https it is redirecting to another website, which i am not linked to.
2. http://mywebsite.com is showing my website itself. (no issues).

I checked .htaccess file, nothing suspicious found.
There is no redirection provided in the cpanel too.

Please advice and thanks in advance.

Comment: Use google chrome. Press F12 to open dev panel. Go to your url. Now view the Network panel and see the response for that url. Click on it and then on the right view the request header and response header. Did you get a 301 redirect or what?

Comment: The status code is mentioned as 200.

Comment: 200 means no redirect. But that could be the second response, after already one redirect. You might still have the other request/response listed in the network panel. Although I think it should be first in chronological order. You could also inspect element and search for html or JavaScript redirects ( "refresh" or "window.location" ).

Answer (score 0):

Many reasons may be provide this issue, here is some suggest

1. Login in to you domain manager board. Check is it redirect to somewhere ?
2. Check apache access log. If your access log that include only php access log, so just check your source code and find some header location. If your access log that include both CSS and JS file, may be your site effect by some XSS attack.